# Mongoengine @property causes multiple loading of user model

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I am adding several properties to my user model by the @property function. Basicaly what it does is doing a call to the cache to retrieve some data which is not in the DB.

What I found was that when I am calling one of the attributes, set by @property, from the flask html template, the property method gets executed again.

I will try to explain it:

First, the user model (it has more fields, but this is not relevant):

```
class User(db.Document,UserMixin):
creation_date = db.DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.now)
activation_code = db.StringField()
email = db.EmailField(required=True,unique=True)
name = db.DictField(required=True)
password = db.StringField(required=True)

@property
def score(self):
    x = redis_userScore.get(str(self.id))
    return x

@property
def questionCount(self):
    print('Thomas')
    x = redis_questionsPerUser.zscore('questions', str(self.id))
    return x
```

Now I added a simple print statement to the @property to test how many times it is run.

In an empty template, this zero. But now in my template, I for instance call:

```
{{ (current_user.score) }}
```

Now I see this print statement being printed. Now I change the template and it looks like this:

```
{{ (current_user.score) }}
{{ (current_user.score) }}
```

The print statement is there twice! The function has been run twice.

This tells me that everytime I am using one of the attributes under @property in the template, it gets run. This makes the application unnecessarily slow. I had expected the attributes to behave the same as the 'normal' ones, like name, email etc. So when I load current_user, the attributes are added and can be used without running it again.

How can I add the extra field to the model, without running it every time it gets called? Just like it works for the other, 'normal', fields.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The @property of python are simply convenient getter, they don’t cache the returned value by default. Caching the returned value can be achieved with the following pattern.

```
class User():
    def __init__(self):
        self._score = None

    @property
    def score(self):
        if self._score is None:
            self._score = self.get_from_cache()
        return self._score

    def get_from_cache(self):
        print(“fake call to cache”)
        return 1000
```

The example here is plain python, but applying that to a MongoEngine Document class is very similar ( constructor will differ as you ll need to call super)

Comment: Did it help? Happy to assist further if not